# Enable disable set radio button when particular date is selected from radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to enable and disable radio button depending on another radio button. When user clicks on particular date radio button time slot of that date as to be enabled. For eg  When the user clicks of date 16-03-2019 time slot of 16-03-2019 8:30am and 1:30pm should be enabled. Other time radio button of 17-03-2019 as to be disabled.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the code:

```
<tr><td><input class="slot" type="radio" name="date" required="" value="16-03-2019">16-03-2019</td>
<td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time" value="8:30 am">8:30am</td>
<td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time" value="1:30 am">1:30pm</td>


</tr> 
 <tr><td><input type="radio" class="slot" name="date" required="" value="17-03-2019">17-03-2019</td>
<td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time" value="8:30 am">8:30am</td>



</tr> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slot').click(function() {
            $('.disabled').prop('checked', false);
            $('.disabled').attr('disabled',true);
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id.split('_');
            id = id[1];
            $('#time_1_'+id).attr('disabled',false);
            $('#time_2_'+id).attr('disabled',false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: there is no ID in the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first set all the radio buttons to *disabled*, then remove the *disabled* property only from the closest *tr*'s radio buttons.

Try the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.slot').click(function() {
        $('.disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.disabled').each(function(i, r){
          $(r).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="slot" type="radio" name="date" required="" value="16-03-2019">16-03-2019</td>
    <td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time" value="8:30 am">8:30am</td>
    <td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time" value="1:30 am">1:30pm</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" class="slot" name="date" required="" value="17-03-2019">17-03-2019</td>
    <td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time" value="8:30 am">8:30am</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Mamun, he can check time slot 8:30am and change the date, previous time slot also should be removed

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda, there is nothing mentioned clearly on this in the question:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add row counter in `<tr>` tag :
HTML :

```
<tr data-row="1">
    <td><input class="slot" type="radio" name="date1" required="" value="16-03-2019">16-03-2019</td>
    <td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time1" value="8:30 am">8:30am</td>
    <td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time1" value="1:30 am">1:30pm</td>
</tr> 
<tr data-row="2">
    <td><input type="radio" class="slot" name="date2" required="" value="17-03-2019">17-03-2019</td>
    <td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time2" value="8:30 am">8:30am</td>
    <td><input class="disabled" type="radio" name="time2" value="1:30 am">1:30pm</td>
</tr>
```

JQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.slot').click(function()
    {
        var tr_row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-row');
        alert(tr_row);
        //Disable all radio
        $('input[name^=time]').removeClass('enable');
        $('input[name^=time]').addClass('disabled');
        //Enable specific radio row
        $('input[name=time'+tr_row+']').removeClass('disabled');
        $('input[name=time'+tr_row+']').addClass('enable');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I want time to be disabled. When user clicks on 16-03-2019 time slot of 16th i.e 8:30 and 1:30pm should be enabled and 17th time slot 8:30 should be disabled. both the dates 16th and 17th should be enabled